# java path independency

Tags: java

I need to construct a file path inside a java program. Which path separator should I use to
 allow my program to work on both Windows and Unix?

Keep in mind that Windows needs a drive letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `System.getProperty("file.separator")`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java's `File.separator` for system independence.

`separator` is a `static String` member of the File class.

[Here](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/core/files/fileseparator.html)'s an example and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html)'s the javadoc for `File`.

EDIT - Getting the OS info

If you only want to see wether you should add a the `C:`, have a look at [this example](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/OSInformation.shtml) for getting the OS info, then parse the OS string and see whether it's MS Windows.

You may also find question [1298310](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298310/when-getting-drive-information-using-java) useful for getting all drive information.

Comment: how to i deal with the drive C:\ on windows

Answer (score 2):

Use `File.separator` to be platform independent although forward slash `/` works on both windows and unix.

Moreover I'd suggest you to avoid using `File.separator`. If you want to create file in folder do the following:

```
File dir = new File("myfolder"); // no slashes
File file = new File(dir, "myfile.txt"); // no slashes.
```

Use `File.listRoots()` to get all driver letters on Windows or single file root `/` on Unix.

Answer (score 0):

Use `File.separator` to construct your file paths.

Answer (score 0):

You should use java.io.File.separator -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator

Comment: Path Separator is not the same as File Separator.

Answer (score 0):

use [File.seperator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) for  seperator for any operating system.